# Can't get data from backend

Tags: reactjs, heroku, mongoose

I have a todo list web app, I get data when I debug but while I deploy to heroku I can't get data. My login modal also is not working. What can I do?

**Debug**

[image: Debug]

Deployed version

[image]

**my repository**

github.com/amahh014/amahhhelper

**Solution**

I've whitelisted all IP's from mongoDB, now is working

Comment: can you add some code and a little infastructure overview to your post?

Comment: You can press F12 in a browser and check the network tab. My guess is that the request fails because of same origin policy. That means you either make sure your react app and api have the same domain, sub domain and port or that your api provides CORS headers.

Comment: it worked and stopped working after few days

Comment: my repository - https://github.com/amahh014/amahhhelper